# Often getting Error 522 and 524 on the site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I'm often getting the error 522 or 524 on my site (AWS free trial). I stopped the instance, rebooted it, and still, the problem exists. I created a new instance (and copied the entire site from the old one to the new using updraft) and that works pretty good for some days and the problem arises again. I tried disabling all the plugins and no luck. I tried Azure too but it seems that this server doesn't have the issue. I cloned the site from AWS to Azure to test and know how the azure works. But surprisingly the site still in good condition and works perfectly without any errors but I haven't connected this instance with my domain since I'm using it to know the platform better.

Comment: By site, I am assuming it is a website you are trying to host. Can you please add more details on how was the site deployed, what technology and which AWS/Azure components you are using? Details will help the community answer your question.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i'm not so expirenced in it so can you please tell me the details you need so that i can have a look and provide you the details.

Comment: Hey Varun - more details around what technology you are using - such as nodejs,java,etc. How is it deployed - on an EC2 instance or on S3 or cloudfront? How you are testing - using a browser or doing curl commands.

Comment: Hi,I deployed it on an EC2 instance. Have a look at this video - I referred this to deploy it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6w1mifCFH8&t=140s

Comment: Hey Varun - this forum is to present your problem with what is not working for you. It is not troubleshooting on what could go wrong when following a youtube video. Pasting logs of your app, configuration of your web app, etc and what you have done to test this (ping,telnet,screenshots) is what will help you get closer to a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

**server response time took more than the timeout out limit.**

*Follow The Steps:*

1. Add a Simple HTML file and check (If it shows the HTML file then follow step 2)
2. Check your database connections and setting (if you are using rds update host name)